# Get an infinite loop, htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

Small question,

I want my website www.example.nl/nl redirect to www.example.nl/nl/home

But If I do this:

```
Redirect 301 /nl/ https://www.example.nl/nl/home
```

Then I get an infinite loop, because the home url contains the nl variable

What is the best way to fix this :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Redirect` is prefix matching, this will indeed result in a redirect loop. You need to use the `RedirectMatch` directive instead, which uses regex instead of simple prefix matching. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/nl/$ https://www.example.nl/nl/home
```

This now matches a request for `/nl/` *only* and not `/nl/<anything>`.